# Is this js form valid?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a js code which asks the user to input a code. I want to check if it is valid or it is programmed to say : code invalid! And if possible what happens when the code is valid.
Js Code:

```
myApp.prompt('Please enter your code, function (password) {
        myApp.showPreloader('Checking Code...')
setTimeout(function () {
    myApp.hidePreloader();
    form.onsubmit = function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
var files = fileSelect.files;
var formData = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
var file = files[i];
if (!file.type.match('bac.*')) {
continue;
  }
     formData.append('bac[]', file, file.name);
 }
formData.append(name, file, filename);
formData.append(name, blob, filename);
formData.append(name, value);  
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'bachandler.php', true);
xhr.onload = function () {
  if (xhr.status === true) {
  } else {
AlertBac();
}
 };
}
xhr.send(formData);

}, 4000);
    myApp.alert('code invalid ');
});   
}, 5123)
    }
  },
]
 })
 });
```

Comment: Nope, it has a syntax error. Next...

Comment: If you can't even take the time to format your code to make it readable, why would anyone want to take the time to figure out what's going on?

Comment: It is not my code...

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the closing quote in the first line.

```
myApp.prompt('Please enter your code, function (password) {
```

should be

```
myApp.prompt('Please enter your code', function (password) {
```

Comment: I know it has syntax errors because ut is not my code but i must know what it does. Does it really send the code entered by the user to a server and checks if it is valid or it just says "code invalid". Please i need it

Comment: That's not what SO is for.

Comment: Please help! I need it